# How to read and execute $\sum_{1 \leq \ell <m<n} \frac{1}{5^{\ell}3^{m}2^{n}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, summation, notation

> How to read and execute this sum?
> $$\sum_{1 \leq \ell <m<n} \frac{1}{5^{\ell}3^{m}2^{n}}$$

I am having trouble to understand where is my error.

The question does not say, but I am assuming that $\ell$ starts at $1$, $m$ at $2$, and so $n$ at $3$.

This is essential a product of pg:

$$\sum_{1 \leq \ell<m<n} \frac{1}{5^{\ell}3^{m}2^{n}} = \sum_{\ell=1}\frac{1}{5^{\ell}}\sum_{m=2}\frac{1}{3^{m}}\sum_{n=3}\frac{1}{2^{n}} = \frac{1/5}{1-1/5}\frac{1/9}{1-1/3}\frac{1/8}{1-1/2}$$
But this does not agree with the answer :/

Comment: You seem not to respect the constraints $\ell<m$, $m<n$.

Comment: Your error is a big one. It is like saying $a_1b_1c_1 + a_2b_2c_2=(a_1+a_2)(b_1+b_2)(c_1+c_2)$.An anology- There are asking for 3 nested loops whereas you are taking 3 seperate loops and multiplying them

Comment: I would not *execute* the sum.  But I may *evaluate* it.

Comment: Note $n$ is not an index, but $n−1$ is an upper limit instead. An assumption that $n$ is not fixed is *not admissible*. Consider for instance $\sum_{0\leq l<n}q^l=\sum_{l=0}^{n-1}q^l=\frac{1-q^n}{1-q}$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. *Assuming $n$ is not fixed:*

Rewrite as triple sum
$$\sum_{1 \leq \ell <m<n} \frac{1}{5^{\ell}3^{m}2^{n}} = \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty\sum_{m=\ell+1}^\infty\sum_{n=m+1}^\infty\frac{1}{5^{\ell}3^{m}2^{n}} =\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^\ell} \sum_{m=\ell+1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^m} \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} $$
Then, this should be obvious in terms of how to read and execute.

Indeed, since each of them are [Geometric Progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_progression#Geometric_series), we have
$$\begin{align}\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^\ell} \sum_{m=\ell+1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^m} \sum_{n=m+1}^\infty \frac{1}{2^n} &= \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^\ell} \sum_{m=\ell+1}^\infty \frac{1}{3^m} \left(\frac{1}{2^m}\right) \\&= \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^\ell} \sum_{m=\ell+1}^\infty \frac{1}{6^m} \\&= \sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \frac{1}{5^\ell}\left(\frac{1}{5\cdot 6^\ell}\right) \\& = \frac{1}{5}\sum_{\ell=1}^\infty \frac{1}{30^\ell} \\&= \frac{1}{5}\cdot\frac{1}{29} \\&= \frac{1}{145}\end{align} $$

---

2. *Assuming $n$ is fixed:*

The sum will be a finite double sum and you can exclude $1/2^n$ from the sum(treating that as a constant). Then, again use the GP formula to calculate each $\ell$-sum and $m$-sum.

Comment: @VIVD: Note the difference between the index regions: $1\leq \ell<m<n$ and $1\leq \ell<m<n<\infty$.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer Yes, you are right. Since the question was quite ambiguous, I added a comment about the second case, as well.

Answer (score 1):

The index region of the sum
\begin{align*}
\sum_{\color{blue}{1\leq \ell <m<n}}\frac{1}{5^{\ell}3^m2^n}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
is specified by the inequality chain
\begin{align*}
1\leq \ell <m<n
\end{align*}
which has $1$ as lower limit and $n$ as upper limit. We have *two* indices $\ell$ and $m$, which means we can write it as double sum as shown in the evaluation below.

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum_{1\leq \ell <m<n}\frac{1}{5^{\ell}3^m2^n}}
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{5^{\ell}}\sum_{m=\ell+1}^{n-1}\frac{1}{3^m}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{5^{\ell}}\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{l+1}-\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^n}{1-\frac{1}{3}}\right)\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{\ell = 1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{5^l}\,\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{3^l}-\frac{1}{3^{n-1}}\right)\tag{4}\\
> &= \frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\sum_{l=1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{15^l}- \frac{1}{2^{n+1}\,3^{n-1}}\sum_{l=1}^{n-2}\frac{1}{5^l}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^{n+1}}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{15}-\left(\frac{1}{15}\right)^{n-1}}{1-\frac{1}{15}}\right)-\frac{1}{2^{n+1}\,3^{n-1}}\left(\frac{\frac{1}{5}-\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)^{n-1}}{1-\frac{1}{5}}\right)\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{1}{2^{n+2}\cdot7}\left(1-\frac{1}{15^{n-2}}\right)-\frac{1}{2^{n+3 }\,3^{n-1}}\left(1-\frac{1}{5^{n-2}}\right)\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=\frac{1}{2^{n+2}\cdot7}-\frac{1}{2^{n+3}\,3^{n-1}}+\frac{1}{2^{n+3}\,3^{n-1}\,5^{n-2}\cdot7}}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (2) we factor out $\frac{1}{2^n}$ and reorder the double sum using another common style.
- In (3) we evaluate the inner sum using the *[finite geometric summation formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)*.
- In (4) we do a simplification and multiply out in the next line.
- In (5) we apply the finite geometric summation formula twice and do a simplification in the following lines.

---

**Note:** A varying upper limit $n$ is **not admissible** in your case. Here $n$ is a *[free variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables#Examples)* whereas the indices $\ell$ and $m$ are bound variables. This is different to the situation
\begin{align*}
\sum_{1\leq \ell <m<n\color{blue}{<\infty}}\frac{1}{5^{\ell}3^m2^n}
\end{align*}
where $n$ is bound by the upper limit $\infty$ and where $n$ varies between $m$ and $\infty$.

*Hint:* You might find chapter 2: *Sums* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Er97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik helpful. It provides a thorough introduction in the usage of sums.

Answer (score 1):

We will assume that $n$ is not fixed.
Firstly, note that for any triple $(l,m,n)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ such that $l<m<n$ there is exactly one triple $(a,b,c)\in\mathbb{N}^3$ such that $l=a$, $m=a+b$, $n=a+b+c$.

Thus, we have the following equality (all terms are positive, so order of summation can be chosen arbitrarily)
$$
\sum_{1<l\le m\le n}\frac{1}{5^l 3^m 2^n}=\sum_{a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{5^{a} 3^{a+b} 2^{a+b+c}}=\sum_{a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{30^a 6^b 2^c}=\sum_{a\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{30^a}\cdot\sum_{b\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{6^b}\cdot\sum_{c\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{1}{2^c}=
\\
=\frac{1}{30-1}\cdot\frac{1}{6-1}\cdot\frac{1}{2-1}\cdot=\frac{1}{145}.
$$

Comment: The assumption that $n$ is not fixed is not admissible in the current situation. Regards,